# Best practices and tutorials for ios authentication

Tags: iphone, ios, authentication, ios6

What are the best practices for creating a user authentication system for an ios application? Any good tutorials or insights on the process are helpful (newbie).

Comment: You at least need an idea of what scope, using your own server or a 3rd part solution (maybe parse.com).

Comment: What are some good third party solutions? I was thinking about running a lamp stack with cakephp and using json to pass the data to my cake auth and so forth. Is that a good practice?

Comment: It could be, if you implement it properly and use all of the appropriate security (do you have your own ssl certificate?)

Comment: not yet but i can get one.  Does parse handle a lot of this for you?

Comment: Actually parse looks really solid, why should I waste time reinventing the wheel when I can use there stuff out of the box?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Stormpath](http://www.stormpath.com/) is an authentication and user management backend service aimed at developers. You manage your own collection of users, verify their logins, and assign users to groups (roles). Your app makes calls to their server.

[Parse](http://www.Parse.com/) provides a [Parse Social](https://parse.com/products/social) service that lets your app do user authentication through Facebook or Twitter. Parse is being [acquired by Facebook](https://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2013/04/25/welcoming-parse-to-facebook/) (as of 2013-04), so I don't know what that means for their future.

[Okta](https://www.okta.com/) is another.

Mozilla [Persona](http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/persona/) is quite promising, but may not yet be ready for the real world. There is an open-source kit for iOS named [persona-ios](https://github.com/mozilla/persona-ios). Read a discussion on [How to use Persona in a native iOS app?](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/mozilla.dev.identity/6atcnwghA_M).

User authentication and identity as as service seems to be a new but burgeoning field.

Comment: THis is more of what I wanted. Thanks.

Comment: [UserApp](https://www.userapp.io) is another user management service. Supports login/signup/password-reset, permissions and features, custom properties to extend the basic user model, social login/OAuth, and more.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using a third party backend the stackmob, parse etc all handle authentication. If you are rolling your own then this project looks a reasonable way to go: http://quickblox.com/developers/SimpleSample-users-ios.